# Color does not contain a definition for green

Tags: c#, itext

I am following the tutorial from the official doc iText7 https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/chapter-4-making-a-pdf-interactive-net.
But it gives Color does not contain a definition for green. And i couldn't find a solution for this error. Any help is appreciated.

```cs
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Annot;
using iText.Layout;
using System;

namespace GeneratePdfDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Must have write permissions to the path folder
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\demo.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);

            // Creating PdfTextAnnotation object
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 800, 0, 0);
            PdfAnnotation ann = new PdfTextAnnotation(rect);

            // Setting color to the annotation
            ann.SetColor(Color.GREEN); // Here is the error

            // Setting title to the annotation 
            ann.SetTitle(new PdfString("Hello"));

            // Setting contents of the annotation       
            ann.SetContents("Hello World.");

            // Creating a new page       
            PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage();

            // Adding annotation to a page in a PDF
            page.AddAnnotation(ann);
            
            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `ColorConstants.GREEN`? https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_colors_1_1_color_constants.html

Comment: Try `Color.Green`

Comment: Same: Color does not contain a definition for Green.

Comment: Is this a WinfForms application?

Comment: Looks like they were removed a while back in favor of ColorConstants. https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/commit/150651dacb0bd604ac57721313a20d176cddf7d0

Comment: No, I only try to manipulate a pdf file with itext7 on dotnet.

Comment: You might need to add a `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: ColorConstants.GREEN removes the error but the color remains yellow ...

Comment: using System.Drawing; doesn't work as well.

Comment: If you use `System.Drawing` it must also be `Color.Green`.

Comment: Although maybe try `BaseColor.GREEN`

Comment: it now gives the name color doesn't exist in current context

Comment: neither basecolor or color works for system.drawing.

Comment: I tried your code with `ColorConstants.GREEN` using itext7 7.2.3 installed with NuGet and it's green for me. *shrug* Did you run the program again after making the change?

Comment: I did. Somehow it doesn't work. The program is able to run. But it still appears yellow.

Comment: May depend on how you are viewing it. In SumatraPDF the color changes. In both Chrome and Edge the color is always yellow.

Comment: You are right, i use edge to view pdf. THanks!